# Having a slight problem moving my camera based on time passed using GLUT/OpenGL

Tags: opengl, animation, glut

Before anyone asks, this is for a university project and **I have to use GLUT**. I'm not tagging this as homework because this is not a requirement, nor will I have extra points for this.

With GLUT, for people unaware, you have:

- `glutIdleFunc(func)`: registers the render function and this means that when GLUT is not doing anything else, it will call this function. In other words, it will keep rendering as fast as possible.
- `glutTimerFunc(msecs, func, val)`: registers a function that will be called in `msecs` and the registering the same function recursively would allow for a fixed time based movement.

Now, I'm trying to avoid these functions for this purpose and most discussions/articles I found about GLUT, use them for time based movement. So I have come here once again... But if I'm not using any of those functions, how are the frames rendered? I just call `glutPostRedisplay` and a single frame will be rendered.

I have managed to implement time based movement in GLUT in a simple manner. May not be the best implementation, but it's not overly complex and works. Well, there's only a slight problem, that's why I'm here.

My camera movement is based on Newton's Second Law of Motion, where I calculate the displacement movement like this:

```
Vector3D displacement = (CurrentVelocity * elapsedTime) +
    (Acceleration * 0.5f * elapsedTime * elapsedTime);
```

The `elapsedTime` comes from my timer implementation and I think that's where the problem lies. The problem is that `displacement` should be positive or negative depending on the movement direction but if `CurrentVelocity` is a really low value (ie: -0.1f), the `displacement` will be positive when it should be negative. The rest of the code will accelerate or deacelerate the camera, so the problem only happens when accelerating because that's when `CurrentVelocity` will be small and what happens is that the camera moves slightly to the right (positive) and then to the left (negative) when it gains enough momentum to give a negative `displacement` value.

Now, when there's no movement in the scene, nothing is being rendered at all. When I press on of the movement keys, I do this:

```
CameraDirection.z = CAMERA_WALK_BACKWARD;
SceneTimer.PostRedisplayWindow();
```

That also comes from my timer class, I do that instead of calling `glutPostRedisplay` and the reason for that is this:

```
void Timer::PostRedisplayWindow(void) {
    currentTime = glutGet(GLUT_ELAPSED_TIME);
    glutPostRedisplay();
}
```

I need to get the `currentTime` (which will become the `previousTime` when I need to calculate the elapsed time) and then I call `glutPostRedisplay`. A single frame will be rendered, which means the `renderScene` will be called:

```
void renderScene(void) {
    (...)

    glLoadIdentity();

    elapsedTime = SceneTimer.GetElapsedTimeInSeconds();

    SceneCamera.Move(CameraDirection, elapsedTime);
    SceneCamera.LookAt();

    drawCompleteScene();

    glutSwapBuffers();

    checkAnimationRedisplay();
}
```

As you can see, the elapsed time is calculated and the camera is moved on that. Everything in the scene is drawn, swap buffers and then I have this extra function which will check if something needs to be animated, in this case, the camera needs:

```
void checkAnimationRedisplay(void) {
    if(SceneCamera.IsCameraMoving()) {
        glutPostRedisplay();
        return;
    }
}
```

It will keep calling `glutPostRedisplay` until the camera has stopped moving. Meaning, `renderScene` will be called every time, the elapsed time is calculated and the camera is moved based on time, everything's working; besides, of course, the little glitch already mentioned, little but the one that made me create this long question (sorry about that).

All that's missing is the most important function of this question, the one that calculates the elapsed time, simple as this:

float Timer::GetElapsedTimeInSeconds(void) {
    static int previousTime = 0;
    static int elapsedTime = 0;

```
previousTime = currentTime;
currentTime = glutGet(GLUT_ELAPSED_TIME);
elapsedTime = currentTime - previousTime;

return elapsedTime / 1000.0f;
```

}

There's probably something wrong with my timer code right? I mean, moving forward or right (positive values), there's no problems. The movement is smooth and time based. For instance, if I set a movement speed of 5m/s, it will actually take 5 seconds to move 25meters (I'm assuming 1m = 1.0f).

So, what I'm doing wrong with the timer so that the negative values start moving to the right for a split-second and only then to the left as it should?

**EDIT:**

A little more code as requested, this is how the `CurrentVelocity` is how calculated and how the displacement is applied:

```
void Camera::Move(Vector3D direction, float elapsedTime) {
    // Move only if the velocity vector is not of zero length (guards against
    // floating point rounding erros
    if(CurrentVelocity.SquaredMagnitude() != 0.0f) {
        Vector3D displacement = (CurrentVelocity * elapsedTime) +
            (Acceleration * 0.5f * elapsedTime * elapsedTime);

        Vector3D ForwardVector = Reference;

        if(cameraType != CAMERA_TYPE_SPECTATOR) {
            ForwardVector = Vector3D::CrossProduct(WORLD_SKY_VECTOR, RightVector);
            ForwardVector.Normalize();
        }

        Position = Position + (RightVector * displacement.x);
        Position = Position + (WORLD_SKY_VECTOR * displacement.y);
        Position = Position + (ForwardVector * displacement.z);
    }

    UpdateCameraVelocity(direction, elapsedTime);
}

void Camera::UpdateCameraVelocity(const Vector3D direction, float elapsedTime) {
    // Accelerate camera if the direction is -1 or 1 or decelerate if it's 0
    if(direction.x != 0.0f) {
        // Accelerate the camera
        CurrentVelocity.x += direction.x * Acceleration.x * elapsedTime;

        // Don't let it go beyond the max velocity
        if(CurrentVelocity.x > MaxVelocity.x) {
            CurrentVelocity.x = MaxVelocity.x;
        } else if(CurrentVelocity.x < -MaxVelocity.x) {
            CurrentVelocity.x = -MaxVelocity.x;
        }
    } else {
        // Decelerate the camera in the correct direction
        if(CurrentVelocity.x > 0.0f) {
            CurrentVelocity.x -= Acceleration.x * elapsedTime;

            // Don't let it start move in the opposite direction
            if(CurrentVelocity.x < 0.0f) {
                CurrentVelocity.x = 0.0f;
            }
        } else {
            CurrentVelocity.x += Acceleration.x * elapsedTime;

            // Don't let it start move in the opposite direction
            if(CurrentVelocity.x > 0.0f) {
                CurrentVelocity.x = 0.0f;
            }
        }
    }

    // All code below was removed, it's similar for all other axis...
}

bool Camera::IsCameraMoving(void) {
    return CurrentVelocity.SquaredMagnitude() != 0.0f;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does the problem occur whenever you change the direction or only when changing from positive values to negative values? If it is always, it is most likely the last acceleration stored from last movement which is still slightly bigger than zero. How do you determine that the movement is over in IsCameraMoving() ?

Can you show the entire calculation of CurrentVelociy and Acceleration and how you apply the displacement?

Also double check that you reset all components of CameraDirection properly.

Edit:

Solution: The `displacement` calculation in `Camera::Move()` was wrong. `Acceleration` must also be multiplied with `direction` here as also done in `Camera::UpdateCameraVelocity`, otherwise it points into the wrong direction.

`Vector3D displacement = (CurrentVelocity * elapsedTime) + (direction * Acceleration * 0.5f * elapsedTime * elapsedTime);`

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question... The `Acceleration` vector is a fixed, it never changes, so of course the "last acceleration" is stored, unless that was not what you meant. `IsCameraMoving` checks the `CurrentVelocity` vector length and if it's zero, it means the camera is stopped. `CameraDirection` values are set to `0` as soon as the keyboard button was released. I could post the whole code but I don't think it's relevant. I wasted too many hours looking for the problem and it's not on `CurrentVelocity` is calculated, `CurrentVelocity` will always be negative moving to the left...

Comment: ...or always positive moving to the right. And like I already said, `Acceleration` is not calculated is a fixed positive value for all 3 axis. But basically, `CurrentVelocity` is a multiplication of: direction (1 or -1) * acceleration (fixed positive value) * elapsed time. The problem is on the displacement that it should *always*  be negative if I'm moving on `-1` direction (left on the x axis). The formula left side `(CurrentVelocity * elapsedTime)` is always negative moving to the left and always positive to the right, the right side `(Acceleration * 0.5f * elapsedTime * elapsedTime)`...

Comment: ...is the one giving problems. it will always be a positive number since `Acceleration` is positive and all the next multiplications will be with positive numbers. When `CurrentVelocity` is a very small value (but negative, moving to the left), the left side will be negative but the right one will be of a positive number enough that the sum of the two will give a positive number, making the camera move slightly to the right side and only then to the left side when `CurrentVelocity` increases enough for the sum of both sides to give a negative value.

Comment: From the minimal part of code posted, one can tell if the acceleration was fixed, the camera would only move in one direction and never into the opposite direction. The key is the calculation of velocity and acceleration, it would be easier to help if you post that part :)

Comment: Thanks for posting the code. The problem is: the Acceleration is only adjusted into the right direction in the first formula, in the 2nd it has the wrong sign.

`1) CurrentVelocity.x += direction.x * Acceleration.x * elapsedTime;` 

`2) Vector3D displacement = (CurrentVelocity * elapsedTime) + (Acceleration * 0.5f * elapsedTime * elapsedTime);`

Adjust the direction of the Acceleration in the 2nd formula too:

`Vector3D displacement = (CurrentVelocity * elapsedTime) + (direction * Acceleration * 0.5f * elapsedTime * elapsedTime);`

Comment: .. Or even better and cleaner: set the acceleration vector correctly according to its direction in the first place.

Comment: Fixing the acceleration fixes the problem, why I never thought of that is beyond me. What's confusing me is that most of my code I took from some sample code I found on Google and the code is very similar. In that version, the acceleration vector is never fixed with the direction but this problem doesn't exist there.

Comment: What do you mean by "set the acceleration vector correctly according to its direction in the first place"? The acceleration vector is of fixed values, I can't change it with the direction cause when the camera is not moving, the direction is 0 and if I multiply that, then the acceleration will be 0 and the camera won't move. The acceleration value is decided on the initialization, I would have to keep that value at hand to prevent the acceleration from being 0, but that's the same as calculating the acceleration with the direction on the fly when I need it. Maybe there's a better way?

Comment: Great to hear it works :) About the fixed Acceleration: The acceleration in terms of Newtons Law is a vector, which basically means it has a direction and a magnitude/length. Now if the acceleration is fixed, that means its direction is fixed, the object will always move _only_ into that direction of the acceleration, but thats not what you want, your object must be able to move into different directions, so the acceleration can't be fixed.

Comment: Let's have a look at Newtons 2nd Law of Motion: `F = m * a`, the Force _F_ and the Acceleration _a_ are important here, ignore the mass _m_, you can simply see it as a scalar here that adjusts the units. The law says the force and acceleration will point into the same direction. So if you change the force acting on your camera, i.e. to make it move into the opposite direction, the formula tells you how the acceleration changes too in respect to it.

Comment: Now actually in terms of Newtons law the `direction` variable is the force `F`, so it would be good to change the name of the variable, it improves the physics conformity of your code.

Comment: When I say "set the `acceleration` in the first place" I mean to calculate it in `Camera::Move()`, change its first param from `direction` to `Force` like this `Camera::Move(Vector3D Force, float elapsedTime)`, then its simply `Acceleration = Force` with a mass implicitely set to `1`.

Comment: To add a proper cam-mass to your simulation, just change the formula to `Acceleration = Force / mass`  or `Acceleration = Force * 1/mass` and there you go, now its Newtos 2nd Law of motion:) and the proper acceleration is stored in the code, so you can safely use the original physics integration formulas `v += a * delta_t` which is: `CurrentVelocity += Acceleration * elapsedTime` and the 2nd formula you used `p += v*delta_t + a*0.5*t*t` which is: `Vector3D displacement = (CurrentVelocity * elapsedTime) + (Acceleration * 0.5f * elapsedTime * elapsedTime);`

Comment: I don't think I can do that, currently the acceleration vector has a fixed value of 8.0f and you're telling me to replace it with the direction (force) vector. If I do that, the acceleration will be very slow. That value can't be 1, it needs to be something greater, that's why it's the acceleration. I don't need this to be be "proper physics", it's fine the way it is. The mass is implicit and it's assumed as 1unit, good enough in the context of what I'm making.

Comment: You can keep a magnitude of 8.0f for the force/acceleration, only the direction must be adjusted. I think you are mistaken the direction of the acceleration with its magnitude. You can have a fixed magnitude of 8.0 and still change the direction, an acceleration of {-8, 0, 0} is also an acceleration of 8.0, just to the left, not to the right. The amount of acceleration is the same.

Comment: "the acceleration vector has a fixed value of 8.0f " That's not quite true, look at the fix that you just did, you change it over and over again by multiplying with `direction` and so recalculation the _real_ `acceleration`. If you do it once and store the proper `acceleration` then you eliminate a great source of future errors, like the one you just fixed, just because the value in `acceleration` had the wrong sign. However, the problem is fixed this time, that's what matters, just wrote it because you asked: "Maybe there's a better way?" Good luck :)

Comment: Could you please edit your answer above with the real answer that actually fixed the problem so I can mark this as accepted? Thanks.

Comment: Done, added fix to the answer above

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be better (just cpu performance) this formula:

```
Vector3D displacement = ((CurrentVelocity + (direction * Acceleration * 0.5f * elapsedTime)) * elapsedTime);
```

Instead of given one

```
Vector3D displacement = (CurrentVelocity * elapsedTime) + (direction * Acceleration * 0.5f * elapsedTime * elapsedTime);
```

as it has 1 less operation?